# Javascript switch from quirksmode to standard

Tags: javascript, quirks-mode

Is there a way to switch a page in quirksmode to standards mode using Javascript?

For example, assuming I have the following page with html in it.  I've tried the following.

```
<html><script src="js.js"></script></html>
```

and the following content in js.js

```
document.open();
document.write('<!doctype html><html></html>');
document.close();
```

From looking at the output above I'm basically trying to convert a page in quirksmode to standards mode, but it doesn't work. (setting the contents of a page like above on an iframe works fine)

### iframe Works

It works you do `document.createElement('iframe')` append into the document and call `iframe.contentWindow.document.write('<!doctype html>..');` on it.  Unfortunately the same technique does not if I'm calling it on the current page.

#### Does anyone have a working fix switching a page in quirksmode to standards mode?

**EDIT:** Creating and appending an iframe and simply setting its height and width to 100%, works but isn't the goal here ;)

Comment: Who writes HTML without a doctype these days?  And why can't you just edit the HTML to include one?

Comment: @Ranyos yeah setting `document.write` doesn't work, but I find it funny that it works if you create an iframe.  I wonder why?

Comment: @cHao that's dodging the original question ;)

Comment: @Lime the content inside the iframe is in standards mode. Not the original page

Comment: @Lime, the iframe thing works inside the iframe only, the outer document will remain in quirksmode.

Comment: @Lime: The original question isn't the one that needed to be asked.  :)

Comment: @bfavaretto  An iframe is supposed to be a window to another document, yet they behave differently.  You can change the doctype of an iframe but not the current page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help with: jquery prepend doctype to html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493845/need-help-with-jquery-prepend-doctype-to-html)

Comment: @cHao the entire [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) site is written without a doctype, not really sure why?

Comment: @Lime: First guess is, cause the devs aren't too bright.  There are just too many issues with quirks mode, and every browser in common use will disable it if there's a doctype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser typically looks for a doctype *at load time* to determine whether to use "standards mode" or not, and loads/renders the page based on that decision.  Even if you managed to insert a doctype declaration via script, it wouldn't be there in time to matter.

The reason it works in an iframe is that the content is a new document, which is being "loaded" as you write it.  Since the doctype is there, that content is rendered in standards mode.

As mentioned in [another question on this same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493845/need-help-with-jquery-prepend-doctype-to-html), you *might* be able to get away with rewriting the whole document.  Basically, (if the page is still in quirks mode,) get `document.documentElement.innerHTML`, and then write a new document with the proper doctype, and append the HTML from the original document.  But it  will cause a bunch of issues with scripts and such, and should be avoided.  The ideal solution is to fix the HTML to include a doctype, rather than fudging it with a script.

Comment: Your (linked)solution worked! Thanks dude, could you either edit your current answer or post another one.  I could close the question altogether, but you did theoritically answer it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
document.open();
document.write('<!doctype html><html></html>');
document.close();
</script>
```

or any variant will not work, because a `<SCRIPT>` tag causes the HTML parser to create an HTML element and a HEAD element if none exists.  By the time an HTML element exists (even an implicit one), a DOCTYPE on the token stream is ignored.

Closing and reopening the document will just prevent parsing of any of the following HTML content.

The only way to use `document.write` to output a DOCTYPE is to create a new blank document that you can write in.

Just solve this server-side.

Comment: If it actually got rid of the document and created a new one, how would your script run?  Part of clearing the document would be to remove the script...

Comment: It's what the mozilla docs [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open)  Thought they were trustworthy :| urg...  Guess I have to make a new plan....

Comment: @Lime, reopening the document would halt HTML parsing preventing the rest of the HTML from being loaded into the new document.  You would, at best, end up with a document in standard mode devoid of content.

Comment: No content in standard mode is better then quirksmode :D at least for me

Comment: @Lime, Then start your file with `<script>document.write("<noscript>");</script>` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing a X-UA-Compatible meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```