# IE change quirks mode to standard mode by javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there a way to make IE change quirks mode to standard mode by javascript? I do not have permission to modify the html content header; and adding a new IE=edge meta tag to head doesn't work (it gives a message say mode has been established and cannot change).

Comment: See this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047158/javascript-switch-from-quirksmode-to-standard

Comment: But don't do that. If you have control over the HTML, which you should if Quirksmode is your problem, find the source of the issue and fix it properly. If it's not your broken HTML or lack of a doctype, the server is setting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to change it and that feature is made to developers to test their websites on olde