# Edit a <script> tag in the <head> before it loads and runs the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce, html-head

I am on an e-commerce platform where I can edit the `<head>`, however some things that are injected into the head are out of reach for users.  So even though we can edit the `<head>`, there are injections which are out of reach and therefore unremovable via the traditional method.
**PS: I can put script before or after these injected JS script tags, which are generated and populated along with my scripts.  And so my script would run before the injected tags if I place my script before their "tag injection line."**

---

### The Problem

The problem is, this platform started injecting analytics and spam into the head, basically jacking our customers info and selling it to third parties.   So I want to disable their crappy scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/some.JS.file.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/another.JS.file.min.js"></script>
```

---

### The Question

Is it possible with javascript or jquery to write a script that will edit  tags before they run?   <s>I can insert this custom script before the  tags are in injected.</s> I was wrong -- the unwanted `<script>` tags are always PREpended to the first non-commented `<script>` tag, and so no javascript will work to hack up the tags before they run.

---

#### What I Have Tried So Far

I found this incomplete and not working answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270694/remove-an-injected-analytics-library-from-browser-memory-in-bigcommerce).

When I run the full script with the right details entered for my own site, **I get so many errors** it's difficult to know where to begin as I have no idea what all the XHR stuff is for or what it does, and some of the errors are ones I've never even seen before.

When I run just this part, which I somewhat understand:

```
doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""+(document.title || ""));

scripts = doc.getElementsByTagName("script");
//Modify scripts as you please
[].forEach.call( scripts, function( script ) {
    if(script.getAttribute("src") == "/some.JS.file.min.js"
       || script.getAttribute("src") == "/another.JS.file.min.js") {

        script.removeAttribute("src");
    }
});
```

#### EDIT UPDATE:

Their script is inserted AFTER my scripts. That is, I can insert the script into the `<head>` before their script tags or after. We are looking into new platforms now but I still need to solve this in the meantime as it will be months before we switch. I was hoping g there is some JavaScript I am not aware of that can edit HTML script tags before they run, if this script runs before they do.

#### EDIT 2:

[Nit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31419750/4206306) `window.bcanalytics = function () {};` works great and breaks most of it by breaking `window.bcanalytics.push` but somehow some of it still survives.

In this block:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
    window.bcanalytics || (window.bcanalytics = []), window.bcanalytics.methods = ["debug", "identify", "track", 
        "trackLink", "trackForm", "trackClick", "trackSubmit", "page", "pageview", "ab", "alias", "ready", "group", 
        "on", "once", "off", "initialize"], window.bcanalytics.factory = function(a) {
        return function() 
        {
            var b = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            return b.unshift(a), window.bcanalytics.push(b), 
            window.bcanalytics
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < window.bcanalytics.methods.length; i++) 
    {
        var method = window.bcanalytics.methods[i];
        window.bcanalytics[method] = window.bcanalytics.factory(method)
    }
    window.bcanalytics.load = function() {
        var a = document.createElement("script");
        a.type = "text/javascript", 
        a.async = !0, a.src = "http://cdn5.bigcommerce.com/r-2b2d3f12176a8a1ca3cbd41bddc9621d2657d707/app/assets/js/vendor/bigcommerce/analytics.min.js";
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
// This line still runs and loads analytics.min.js
// This line still runs and loads analytics.min.js
// This line still runs and loads analytics.min.js
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b)
// ^^^ This line still runs and loads analytics.min.js
// This line still runs and loads analytics.min.js
// This line still runs and loads analytics.min.js
    }, window.bcanalytics.SNIPPET_VERSION = "2.0.8", window.bcanalytics.load();
    bcanalytics.initialize({"Fornax": {"host": "https:\/\/analytics.bigcommerce.com","cdn": "http:\/\/cdn5.bigcommerce.com\/r-2b2d3f12176a8a1ca3cbd41bddc9621d2657d707\/app\/assets\/js\/vendor\/bigcommerce\/fornax.min.js","defaultEventProperties": {"storeId": 729188,"experiments": {"shipping.eldorado.ng-shipment.recharge-postage": "on","shipping.eldorado.label_method": "on","cp2.lightsaber": "on","PMO-272.cp1_new_product_options": "on","cart.limit_number_of_unique_items": "control","cart.auto_remove_items_over_limit": "control","BIG-15465.limit_flash_messages": "control","BIG-15230.sunset_design_mode": "control","bigpay.checkout_authorizenet.live": "on","bigpay.checkout_authorizenet.live.employee.store": "control","bigpay.checkout_authorizenet.test": "on","bigpay.checkout_authorizenet.test.employee.store": "control","bigpay.checkout_stripe.live": "on","bigpay.checkout_stripe.live.employee.store": "control","bigpay.checkout_stripe.test": "on","bigpay.checkout_stripe.test.employee.store": "control","sessions.flexible_storage": "on","PMO-439.ng_payments.phase1": "control","PMO-515.ng_payments.phase2": "control","PROJECT-331.pos_manager": "control","PROJECT-453.enterprise_apps": "control","shopping.checkout.cart_to_paid": "legacy_ui","onboarding.initial_user_flow.autoprovision": "on","faceted_search.enabled": "off","faceted_search.displayed": "off","themes.previewer": "enabled"}},"defaultContext": {"source": "Bigcommerce Storefront"},"anonymousId": "24a35a36-7153-447e-b784-c3203670f644"}});
})();
</script>
```

`window.bcanalytics.load` manages to survive and loads analytics.min.js (according to the Network tab), though I can't tell if the script then runs or doesn't.

Also, I've figured out that these pesky HTML lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="" async="" src="http://tracker.boostable.com/boost.bigcommerce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" defer="" src="http://cdn5.bigcommerce.com/r-2b2d3f12176a8a1ca3cbd41bddc9621d2657d707/javascript/jirafe/beacon_api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://cdn5.bigcommerce.com/r-2b2d3f12176a8a1ca3cbd41bddc9621d2657d707/app/assets/js/vendor/bigcommerce/analytics.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ecommerce.js"></script>
```

are Always PREpended to the first non-commented `<script>` opening tag, so unfortunately, none of the creatively destructive methods below will work, as any script I try to insert ahead of these tags will automatically find the pesky unwanted lines appended before it.

Comment: If it is injected and you can interact with it, it will be loaded....

Comment: You cannot prevent the scripts from running. The browser will run the scripts as soon as it sees the closing `</script>` tag.

Comment: Time to move to a more respectable platform/server

Comment: It is impossible to "unload" their scripts if yours get loaded after it. However, you can try to break their codes to stop it from working.

Comment: You *might* also be able to block unwanted requests with [CSP](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/).

Comment: I would suggest ditching the bad system and using a system which doesn't compromise your users' privacy. However, if the script is inserted after your script then yes you can, if not then no you cannot.

Comment: Their script is inserted AFTER my scripts.  That is, I can insert the script into the `<head>` before their script tags or after.  We are looking into new platforms now but I still need to solve this in the meantime as it will be months before we switch. I was hoping g there is some JavaScript I am not aware of that can edit HTML script tags before they run, if this script runs before they do.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the main reason I need to do this, besides the theft of users behavior data, is because their scripts or the server they're served from seems to be unstable and so loading their scripts often freezes the browser/DOM rendering until the script loads, which more often than not takes longer than a minute!

Comment: When your scripts run the other tags probably don't exist yet and as soon as they do they will be compiled. Are you sure you haven't been hacked by xsss injection also?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change platforms stat. And/or contact the current platform and tell them to stahp. You are currently probably conspirator to violating a few laws through this.

Comment: @Tiny Giant, but how?!

Comment: You can not access elements before they are added. Unless you can hijack what is adding the scripts, there is nothing you can really do with JavaScript.

Comment: @Tiny, I am going to try it in an hour, as I get back home. Thank you.  At charlietfl, I think they do exist. That is, as I understand the DOM/page generation/population, is done via PHP.  When I insert my JS before their scripts, their scripts on the HEAD template that I can edit is in the form of a "global variable" defined by their PHP backend, something like %%GLOBAL_Crap%%.   The problem here is, I can't remove that line unless I also want to remove some other important shopping cart JS, etc. When page is generated, that %%GLOBAL%% line outputs a bunch of script tags, AFTER my script.

Comment: php vs browser compiling are different things, read up on how browser compiles a page. Not a simple task but if they put their methods in global namespace you could overwrite them. Most likely they are insulated within closures though

Comment: @charlietfl, oh of course. I meant that when the page is generated by browser, it uses a PHP generated HTML page. So if on the back end, I place my script before their script-generating-PHP-defined-line, in the browser, my script will run first, before their tags run. I figured this gave me the opportunity to hack up their script tags so that they either don't run at all, or so that when they run they have an empty SRC.

Comment: What on earth is this platform you're using???

Comment: Missing the point...as soon as browser encounters your tag, it will compile it. The others won't in the DOM yet. Putting your code after is too late also

Comment: Actually, no you cannot, the element will not exist by the time the script runs and therefore cannot be affected until the script has already executed.

Comment: @gnack, BigCommerce. If you do a quick Google search you'll see this is a commonly asked questions. The one I linked is also users looking for a solution to this. But I don't want to tag on them too much, their platform has done a lot for businesses even if its not perfect.

Comment: @Tiny Giant, really? As I understand, when the browser downloads the HTML file, all the script tags should already be present, in this case after my script. THEN the browser parses it line by line, parsing my script first and applying it to scripts below. Is my understanding correct? Is it that their script tags haven't been parsed yet and therefore the browser is not aware of them?

Comment: @AndreBulatov I know this isn't really the place to discuss this in depth, but you will need to consider whether removing these scripts is allowed by the terms of use - it probably isn't.

Comment: Only the elements prior to the current script are loaded into the DOM at the time the script executes, and those scripts are only accessible in the DOM once they have been executed.

Comment: @AndreBulatov the page executes each script as soon as it hits the end of the <script> tag, that's why you can't use JS to interact with elements further down the DOM unless you wait for an onload event.

Comment: @gnack, you may be right but the offense would be mild and I would be more than happy to have them approach me about it and explain to me why I must have this script on my page, a year after we signed up with them when no such script injections took place. I know they have a ToS - good for them!

Comment: @charlietfl, wow so until the browser parsed the line, the browser is not aware of its existence? Is there a JavaScript method to overtake the bworser parsing, scour through the non-DOM-loaded HTML file, chop up the script tags, and then turn parsing back over to the browser? At this point, all practicality aside, I just want to accomplish this :)

Comment: @AndreBulatov is this the Analytics feature you're talking about?  The wording in their ToS makes it sound like this is a feature that can be disabled - maybe look into that as an alternative option?

Comment: @AndreBulatov the answers posted below are really your only option, if there's no legitimate way to disable them.

Comment: @gnack, appreciated. I'll look into their backend again but I'm skeptical of the ability to disable it. Moreover, its not even a feature we can make use of as that's only for "Enterprise" level plans. And yet, the script is already running and collecting data. They *prolly* don't allow anyone to disable it as it'd lessen their "Enterprise" offering with a history of user behavior stats.

Comment: If it's PHP, can you inject PHP code? If you can use PHP output buffering, you could strip the tags out before they are sent to the client.

Comment: You have to stay on a host doing script injection for *months*!? That sounds awful

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara, hahaha I wish! PHP writing not allowed. What a blessing such a power would be. Like chiiNUT said, its awful out here for an aspiring dev. Or awesome, depending on how you look at it. Look what kind of lessons these people put me through!

Comment: If you need some of the scripts they run for crucial functionality, it really sounds like a difficult task to isolate the good from the bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the offending code is similar to that of the question you linked to, I would simply try to break the offending code so it fails to execute.
From hereon the answer relies on code from the other question since you didn't provide any.

The offending code relies on analytics, which is ensured on the page at the beginning of the script:

```
(function(){
    window.analytics||(window.analytics=[]),window.analytics.methods=["debug","identify","track","trackLink","trackForm","trackClick","trackSubmit","page","pageview","ab","alias","ready","group","on","once","off","initialize"],window.analytics.factory=function(a){return function(){var b=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);return b.unshift(a),window.analytics.push(b),window.analytics}};for(var i=0;i<window.analytics.methods.length;i++){var method=window.analytics.methods[i];window.analytics[method]=window.analytics.factory(method)}window.analytics.load=function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src="http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/r6cb05f0157ab6c6a38c325c12cfb4eb064cc3d6f/app/assets/js/analytics.min.js";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)},window.analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="2.0.8",window.analytics.load();
    //The rest of the script
})();
```

To break the whole script and prevent it from running you should simply assign `window.analytics` a value that will conflict with the methods that are used.
So, for example, you could run a script before the offending script that simply assigns the following:

```
window.analytics = function () {};
```

Which will result in the offending script failing due to a type error.

Comment: I appreciate this but though this seems like a possible solution, the problem is, I need to stop the actual JS files from loading. They cause major hang ups in rendering.

Comment: @AndreBulatov Which is causing a hang, the loading time or the execution of the scripts?

Comment: Yeah, looks like some times its execution, sometimes the loading.  However, I tried your solution and works well most times!  Thing is, this line `b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b)`, withing window.bcanalytics.load still loads. Even though your code initially breaks window.bcanalytics.push, somehow window.bcanalytics is restored for load?

Comment: Updated in detail in Edit 2.

Answer (score 3):

If you know you can at least get your scripts to run first, one (albeit hacky) solution is to just absolutely "trash" the JS environment for the next script, so it has some problems. For example:

```
//trash it
document.getElementById=null;
document.querySelector=null;
document.querySelectorAll=null;
window.console=null;
window.alert=null;
document.getElementsByTagName=null;
document.getElementsByClassName=null;
```

As soon as the enemy script tries using one of those functions, it will just crap out. Those are just some common methods off the top of my head... find out which ones its using, and nuke those. Of course, nuking anything you need for events on your own page could be an issue.

Comment: This is a great concept except the problem is, I need to stop the actual JS files from loading. They cause major hang ups in rendering.

Comment: if you make them break, that is just as good. as soon as one of the scripts tries to use any of the above functions, it will immediately halt and return control back to your page

Comment: the "hang ups" should go away just the same whether the script is crashed or not loaded

Comment: Thank you sir, I will attempt this shortly and report back.

Comment: @chiliNUT That said, the delay he means might be related to the time it takes for the script to be downloaded and loaded, which will still be there even if the script is broken. It's not a bad solution, but it's still not "just as good".

Comment: gotta love the term ....`trash the js environment`! +1 for good laugh on that one

Comment: @chiliNUT he's talking about the time it takes to fetch the JS itself.

Comment: Also, I would recommend saving the values so that you can untrash the js environment afterwards.

Comment: @PeterOlson "just as good" was under the assumption that the delay was caused by the script being laggy and doing a lot of junk that makes the page hang; unless the script is some ungodly filesize I just wouldn't think the size alone would be a factor; but if it is, then yes, agreed, crashing it will not help that

Answer (score 3):

How are the scripts being injected? If it's through something like `document.createElement`, you could attempt to hijack that function and disable it if the element name is `script`:

```
var origCreate = document.createElement;
document.createElement = function (name) {
  if (name.toLowerCase() !== 'script') {
    origCreate.call(document, name);
  }
};
```

Comment: He explained in the comments above, but basically the injection is done server-side.

Answer (score 3):

Since the scripts are being inserted *server-side*, you won't be able to disable the running of the scripts in your JavaScript. However, if you're able to inject *any arbitrary text* before and after the scripts being inserted, you could try commenting out the script tags by inserting this first:

```
  <!--
```

...then this after:

```
  -->
```

If the scripts get injected between these, it will hopefully cause the HTML parser to ignore the scripts.

**Update**:

Sounds like you need to disable just *some* of this content, so commenting everything out won't work. However, if before/after hijacking works, you could potentially wrap the injected scripts in a DOM element, parse that content, strip out the scripts you don't want, and inject the scripts so they run:

Inject something like this before:

```
<style id="hijack" type="text/html">
```

...and this after:

```
</style>
<script>
  var hijackedWrapper = document.getElementById('hijack');
  var scripts = hijackedWrapper.textContent;
  scripts = scripts.replace('<script src="http://some.domain.com/foo.js"></s' + 'cript>', '');
  document.write(scripts); // There's better ways to do this, but is just an illustration
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this can be done. Say you have a script that loads before the hostile scripts, and add a `<!--` after itself. Where does it put the `-->`? Keep in mind that the hostile scripts don't yet exist in the DOM yet.

Comment: This is assuming you have hooks for before _and_ after whatever stage the tags are getting injected during.

Comment: At least that's how I interpreted the comment `I can insert the script into the <head> before their script tags or after.`

Comment: I will look into this again but I don't think it'll work. Fact is, I can insert the <!-- before their script-tag-generating line, and then --> after the line, and it will probably work well - too well!  The issue here is simple -- their script generating line also generates other very necessary ecommercy resources, such as shopping cart and check-out scripts. It would disable the analytics, but also break some crucial functionality.

Comment: If you wanted to get _really_ hacky, you could insert the before/after text to make them not scripts, parse the DOM, strip out the offending parts, then re-insert into the page. :/

Comment: Can you insert a snippet that has a proof-of-concept? I'm curious to see how you dynamically insert HTML comments into a page.

Comment: Your original answer may not have answered the question for OP's specific case, but I think it was still a positive contribution to the discussion, and would be useful for other victims of script injection. I like this one too though

Comment: Added a sample. I have _no idea_ if this will work. Testing.

Comment: Tried this awesome solution, but failed hard.  My fault though.  Solution is great, but alas, I was wrong about how they are injected.   Basically, BC engineers are just as sneaky as we are and are PREpending their script tags to the first non-commented out `<script>` tag.  So this is the end of the road for this method, right?

Answer (score 1):

Like the others, I would suggest sabotaging the js environment for the hostile script, and then recovering it back once you need it.

For example, if the script relies on `document.getElementById`, you can do this

```
var restore = {
  getElementById: document.getElementById
};
document.getElementById = null;
```

and then if you have a need to use `document.getElementById` later, you can restore it back:

```
document.getElementById = restore.getElementById;
```

---

I also wanted to note that removing the actual script tags, as far as I can tell, is not possible:

- If you put in a script before the hostile scripts, then they will not be loaded in the DOM yet, so it can't see anything to remove.
- If you put in a script after the hostile scripts, the hostile scripts will already be loaded.

Comment: Love it! Def gonna try. I just hope I am able to isolate the one or two scripts I need to destroy. The issue is, before I can restore the methods, several other necessary scripts will also load. So, I have control, then ~6 scripts load -- 2 of which I need to block -- then I get control back. Thanks.