# Javascript/Jquery How to compare ID's and if true, not call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript  imported a snow.js file that displays "Snow falling" across the screen for when it's winter. But If I choose a summer theme on the same page it will still display the Snow falling.

```
<script src="js/snow.js" type="text/javascript"><script>
```

Is their a way to create a Javascript code so if i click on a summer theme it will remove/comment the imported file and add/re-move commenting on the imported file when I click on a winter theme?

**Edit:**

I am using snowstorm.JS plugin realized I can call a function "snowStorm.toggleSnow()" via script. But I need to adjust it, so if they click on my css button "Summer" whilst on the theme summer it will do nothing.

<strike>I created this Jquery/JS code but it doesn't work. I believe it's the brackets but not sure. It should solve the problem.</strike>

**Update:**

I got it working, so If the user clicks a button it will "Toggle" the snowstorm effect on and off.

```
$("#Summer").click(function(){

    snowStorm.toggleSnow()


});

$("#Winter").click(function(){

    snowStorm.toggleSnow()



});
```

Is there a way of introducing if loops, so if the user clicks on the same button, eg: ID "Summer" whilst on the same ID/CSS "Summer" it will not toggle the snowstorm?

Comment: More likely than not, "snow.js" is actually a plugin which allows you to disable the effect via a JS API. No need to remove/reload the script. Can you point to the plugin you are using?

Comment: You will have to add additional information on snow.js, to be able to stop its effect.

Comment: Thanks @Grimbode . It's going to be my first time trying to disable a plugin via style switching. Have you got any tips / advice on how I should approach it?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use JS or jQuery to remove the tag.</strike>

For example, in jQuery:

```
$("#summerThemeButton").click(function() {
    $("script[src=js/snow.js]").remove();
});
```

However, as @IgorRaush commented, there's probably a better way to change the theme (probably by a JS API) than to remove the script for it completely.

**EDIT**

As the comments suggest, it's not so easy to remove a JS file by removing the `<script>` tag. It is already executing code. The best way is to use the functions that came with it to stop it. Maybe you want to check if there are functions, such as:

```
var stopSnow = function() { /* ... */ };
var changeTheme = function(newTheme) { /* ... */ };
```

If there are truly no API functions (if you found an API; if you wrote it yourself just write a function!) then your best bet might be to remove all relevant/global variables and functions:

```
// for example, if you had a running function `snow()` or a global variable to make it snow:
snow = null;
theme = null;
```

Sorry there's no better way (I know of) to remove a script.

Comment: It's not editing files, but changing the HTML of the current page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure removing the script tag will actually have no effect... By the time you remove the DOM element, the script has already been loaded and executed. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11577730/1391671) answer.

Comment: This has no effect. Once a javascript file is loaded in memory, removing it from the DOM will have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @Grimbode I just figured this might work, but hadn't tested it. Thanks! I'll come up with another solution.

Comment: @IgorRaush and Grimbode Better now?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I used an API. If I find a way to do it I will let you know

Comment: @Jonathan there is just not enough information in the question to be able to conclude an answer at this point.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $.getScript in jQuery to conditionally load the file. See more at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/