# Remove PHP Error Message at top of page with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, expressionengine

I have a site running on Expression Engine. It appears the webserver was upgraded and now a plugin is throwing an error message. It doesn't seem to be impacting the operation of the site so while I try and remedy the issue I thought I could hide the PHP error message with jquery.

The error message is being put on the page before anything else -> before the DOCTYPE tag.

Here's one line:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Foxee_utils::check_cache() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/noelwhit/public_html/admin/modules/foxee/mod.foxee.php on line 228
```

I was toying with $(document).before() in some way but appear to be a little bit away from greatness just yet.

Thanks.

```
$(document).before()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't stop laughing at this question title.

Comment: And you want to do this instead of fix the problem.. why?

Comment: are only EE super-admins seeing the message? if so why bother?

Comment: Literally laughed so hard I almost peed.

Comment: looks like XY problem :) actually plugin should be fixed, if it is impossible error should be hidden at php side via php.ini or error_reporting, jquery of course can help to hide part of html, but it is so bad solution, I dont want to provide it

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP 5 disable strict standards error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely shouldn't be fixed with jQuery. There are at least two ways to fix the problem with other than jQuery:

1. The hard and proper way. Prefix `Foxee_utils::check_cache()` with `static` keyword:

   ```
   static function check_cache(/* skip */)
   ```
2. The easy way. Add somewhere in the site configuration files, after other call to `error_reporting()` if there is one:

   ```
   error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_STRICT);
   ```

Comment: I had been given this as a fix: "public static function xxx()". The true fix is simply "static function xxx()". Thank you sanmai.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve no it's not. Why would you think that? javascript errors do not appear on page.

Answer (score 1):

[That's a duplicate of many questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242903/php-hide-all-errors) But here's your answer

```
error_reporting(0)
```

At the top of your page

---

EDIT: I will strongly advise to not use this answer but if you really want to hack your way... use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493845/need-help-with-jquery-prepend-doctype-to-html) to help you. Basically you take your inner html, then rewrite your page. But you should sincerely try to solve your problem instead of hiding it... The community is here to help you, make good use of it.

Here's a snippet of his answer :

```
var markup= document.documentElement.innerHTML;
markup= '<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">'+markup+'</html>';
document.open();
document.write(markup);
document.close();
```

Comment: this isn't a javascript solution.

Comment: ...but is certainly a better solution than the hacky solution he is expecting. +1

Comment: true.. but the *best* solution is to fix the actual problem!

Comment: @Crayon Violent
Huh? Oh maybe ! I'm not too sure the question is asked in a weird way. Either way, the question should be more on how to fix it then how to hide it :)

Comment: Have already been down that path. That line already sits in the page.

Comment: @CrayonViolent, now I agree :)

Comment: @Adam Fletcher maybe you should edit your question because it's asked in a weird way.

Comment: Have even tried something like this: 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
... to no avail.

Hence trying to find a hack way around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Michael, It's a PHP error. My question is to find a quick jquery way to hide the error while I work on the PHP fix.